# Touchpad is not sensitive enough

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, libinput

On my new ASUS laptop I have an Elantech touchpad which works great out of the box (I'm running 17.10 beta).
The only problem I have is with sensitivity, which feels not sufficient. For example often the first time I tap on the touchpad, the click is not registered and a second or third tap is required.

Running libinput on a Wayland session, I looked through the relative documentation and found this: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad_pressure.html#touchpad_pressure_hwdb
The problem is that `measure-touchpad-pressure` doesn't seem to be included in the `libinput-tools` package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libinput-tools/filelist)

So, is there a way in which I can tweak my touchpad's sensitivity?

Comment: Isn't there a slider under Mouse$Touchpad?

Comment: That controls cursor speed

Comment: Could this possibly be related to focus-stealing? It seems like focus stealing prevention might cause this so you would have to click two times to register the new focus.

Comment: Either that or it sounds like you might have palm detection on or possibly something to do with the noise cancellation set too high?

Comment: You can run `xinput list` to determine the touchpad device number (like, device number `12` for example). Then, for example, you could run `xinput list-props 12` to list all of the device parameters available. Each one of these parameters is also listed with a number. For example, Synaptics Palm Detection (304). So, to set `Synaptics Palm Detection` on device number `12` to `0` you could run the following command: `xinput set-prop 12 304 0` which would disable palm detection. If you find a setting you like, you can permanently it by including these parameters in your libinput config file.